# SOAP webservice client with javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, authorization, token, webservice-client

I try to write a simple client javascript to access to a SOAP webservice. I found an example on the web

https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Using-Web-Services-with-SOAP-Javascript

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP Javascript Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //replace second argument with the path to your Secret Server webservices
            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://URL//MANU_WSManutenzioni_MOGE/', true);

            //create the SOAP request
            //replace username, password (and org + domain, if necessary) with the appropriate info
            var strRequest =
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soap:Envelope ' +
                    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" ' +
                    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" ' +
                    'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'; +
                    '<soap:Body>' +
                        '<Authenticate xmlns="urn:https://URL">' +
                            '<IdTipologiaSegnalazione>7</IdTipologiaSegnalazione>' +
                            '<IdModalitaSegnalazione>6</IdModalitaSegnalazione>' +
                            '<IdSegnalante>21856</IdSegnalante>' +
                            '<Descrizione>test</Descrizione>' +
                            '<IdTipologiaIntervento>21</IdTipologiaIntervento>' +
                            '<Matricola>emergenze</Matricola>' +
                        '</Authenticate>' +
                    '</soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
            //specify request headers
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'TOKEN');

            //FOR TESTING: display results in an alert box once the response is received
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            };

            //send the SOAP request
            xmlhttp.send(strRequest);
        };

        //build & send the request when the page loads
        window.onload = function() {
            soap();
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The client seem to works but I do not understand how to send an authorization token given by the server authority.

I try with

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'TOKEN');
```

but it do not works

Comment: You're sending an `Authorization` header with the string `TOKEN`. You need to send the actual token.

Comment: I do not write the TOKEN in the question only because the TOKEN is for a private use of my company but in the web page I use the correct token between  single '